# Copy a matrix/2d array to another in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to copy a 2d array into another 2d array, i have these two array created:

```
#define mapXcor 50
#define mapYcor 50

char secondStage    [mapXcor][mapYcor];
char currentStage   [mapXcor][mapYcor];
//mapXcor and mapYcor are constant integers
```

Now my `secondStage[][]` array is populated with values on it, but `currentStage[][]` isn't, and i want to assign the values of `secondStage` to `currentStage`. So i created the function bellow:

```
void populateArray(char (&arrayA)[mapXcor][mapYcor], char arrayB[mapXcor][mapYcor]) {
    for(int a = 0; a < mapXcor + 1; ++a) {
        for(int b = 0; b < mapYcor + 1; ++b) {
            arrayA[mapXcor][mapYcor] = arrayB[mapXcor][mapYcor];
        }
    }
}

populateArray(currentStage[mapXcor][mapYcor],secondStage[mapXcor][mapYcor]);
```

But when i use the function it gives me a error :

> 1   IntelliSense: a reference of type "char (&)[20][50]" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "char"
>
> 2   IntelliSense: argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "char (*)[50]"

How could I fix this?

Comment: Sort of off-topic, but if you don't need to support a jagged matrix, consider using a 1-D array to benefit from contiguous memory throughout. You can convert coordinates with the following: one-d-coord = y * cols + x

Comment: Pass the arrays themselves: `populateArray(currentStage, secondStage);` Your `for` loop conditions are off by one, too.

Comment: @RonDahlgren Still his static arrays (being actual arrays of arrays and not just arrays of pointers) are indeed stored contiguously. But you're right in that a dynamic matrix should never be an array of pointers to dynamic arrays and usually people aren't aware of the difference between an array of arrays and an array of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

change the assignment sentence in your for-loop:

```
arrayA[mapXcor][mapYcor] = arrayB[mapXcor][mapYcor];
```

by

```
arrayA[a][b] = arrayB[a][b];
```

Answer (score 2):

Code you probably are trying to reach. Do not show it to teacher :-) - there is too much from practical programming. Just look and then write your own solutions:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define mapXcor 5
#define mapYcor 5

static char secondStage    [mapXcor][mapYcor];
static char currentStage   [mapXcor][mapYcor];

void populateArray(char (&arrayA)[mapXcor][mapYcor], const char (&arrayB)[mapXcor][mapYcor]) {
/*
    for(int a = 0; a < mapXcor; ++a) {
        for(int b = 0; b < mapYcor; ++b) {
            arrayA[a][b] = arrayB[a][b];
        }
    }
*/
    memcpy(arrayA, arrayB, sizeof(arrayB));
}

int main()
{
    for(int a = 0; a < mapXcor; ++a) {
        for(int b = 0; b < mapYcor; ++b){
            currentStage[a][b] = a*b + 10*a;
        }
    }

    populateArray(secondStage, currentStage);

    for(int a = 0; a < mapXcor; ++a) {
        for(int b = 0; b < mapYcor; ++b){
            printf("%2i ", secondStage[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comments:

- You have bad array index limits in cycle. Look for corrected function
  under comment.
- You have wrong indexes in assignment in cycle. Again, commented out code.
- If you passed one array by reference (destination) why not to use constant reference for source?
- In practice as your areas have the same type (you could even define them as having the same type)
  nobody copies them by elements. I have used memcpy() but this is only good if memory areas do not
  overlap (in this case - yes). check `man 3 memcpy`.
- **Learn harder :-)**

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 2

void copyArray(char (&arrayA)[ROWS][COLS], const char (&arrayB)[ROWS][COLS] ) {

    memcpy(arrayA, arrayB, sizeof(arrayB));
}

int main(void){

    char arr1  [ROWS][COLS];
    char arr2  [ROWS][COLS];

    // init arr1
    copyArray(arr2, arr1);

    return 0;
}
```